# connect(sid, environ) function doesm't work

Tags: flask, server, socket.io, connection, eventlet

i am trying to make a server client connection for deep learning
the client is a self driving car simulator with the same port number
and the server is the code i implemented as follows :

```
import socketio
import eventlet
from flask import Flask

sio = socketio.Server()

app = Flask(__name__)


@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('Connected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 4567)), app)
```

after i run the program, it should print the word Connected when i open the simulator
but once i open it, it only shows that the connection is accepted like the following :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgidC.png)
how can i make the connect function to connect properly ?
i am using pycharm

i tried making a client code but same thing happens
i tried to use some code from the library to test but again, it gave the same response, here is the code i tried:

```
import eventlet
import socketio


sio = socketio.Server()
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, static_files={
    '/': {'content_type': 'text/html', 'filename': 'index.html'}
})

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connect ', sid)

@sio.event
def my_message(sid, data):
    print('message ', data)

@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 4567)), app)
```